# Php input stream conflict

Tags: php, multithreading, inputstream

I am a php newbie. I am using Apache + php + mysql to develop a web application. I have used file_get_content (php://input) to get content of HTTP request from the client, and it works well. My question is , when multiple clients send data at the same time, would apache put all data at the same input stream? Is there any mechanism to use mutex in the input stream?
    Thanks in advance

Comment: why would you do that?? Most people use the $_GET and $_POST superglobal arrays to get that date. Since a PHP script is invoked exactly 1 time per request, and every request is unique, you will never see multiple clients inside the same instance.

Comment: @Tularis - one reason to do it is if the params are sent with content type `application/json` (like angularjs does)

Comment: @Tularis Yes my clients are not necessarily  a browser, and the content could be a xml string, so that I chose to use php://input to read the data

Comment: Ah ok, I was (mistakenly) assuming you were just using regular GET/POST requests